# Talking about the temperature

Tags: grammar

Is it correct this? :

Today is 25°C

Or this:

Today it’s 25°C

And without today:

Is 25°C/ It’s 25°C

Answer (score 6):

In common usage, it would be more correct to say, "**It** is 25°C."

In this context, the "**it**" is generally understood to mean to "the temperature".

For example:

> Today, **it**'s 25°C.
>
> Today, **the temperature** is 25°C.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!!